# Procedure or function income has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have searched the other post regarding the same problem but I could not solve my problem.Please help me solving this.

```
Procedure or function sp_UUMJ has too many arguments specified.
```

I have written the following codes in c# code behind file.

```
string strInsertOverride = "sp_UUMJ";
SqlParameter[] spInsert = new SqlParameter[3];
spInsert[0] = new SqlParameter("@mRegNo", SqlDbType.BigInt);
spInsert[0].Value = Convert.ToInt64(members);
spInsert[1] = new SqlParameter("@added_date", SqlDbType.VarChar,100);
spInsert[1].Value = Yesterday;
spInsert[2] = new SqlParameter("@intResult", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
spInsert[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

int intResult = objDUT.ExecuteSqlSP(spInsert, strInsertOverride);//SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[3];

if (intResult == 0)
{
    Label2.Text = "added";
}
```

below is the function details of ExecuteSqlSP

```
 public int ExecuteSqlSP(SqlParameter[] arrParam, string strSPName)
    {
        OpenConnection();
        _mDataCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _mDataCom.CommandText = strSPName;
        _mDataCom.CommandTimeout = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrParam.Length; i++)
        {
            _mDataCom.Parameters.Add(arrParam[i]);
        }

        _mDataCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int intResult = Int32.Parse(_mDataCom.Parameters["@intResult"].Value.ToString());
        CloseConnection();
        DisposeConnection();
        return intResult;
    }
```

Below are the codes for stored procedure in sql server

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_UUMJ] @mRegNo as bigint,@added_date as varchar(100), @intResult as int output   (have written the parameters only)
```

I have checked the data type in c# file and sql server but the mistakes is not seen by me. I have checked other solutions but I can not figure out the source of error.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: It is quite odd to pass a date to a stored proc as a `varchar`.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. We are particularly interested in how `_mDataCom` is declared and instantiated.

Comment: if `_mDataCom` is a DBCommand object, since you are not creating a new one for this use, it could very well have parameters left over from the last use.  DbCOmmand, DBConnection and the other DB Objects are not meant to be reused

Comment: please check this link https://prnt.sc/k6sdmq I have written all the details above for better understanding but it seems too much details changing your focus.thats why i have shown the problem in simple writing in the image link. Thank you all for help.

Comment: You have not yet provided a [mcve]. I cannot just copy and paste that code into a console app and run it (it won't compile, since `ExecuteSqlSP` is not included etc).

Comment: thanks for your reply. when the exception occurs, the value of _mDataCom.Parameters.Count() ==3. I have updated the post with ExecuteSqlSP. @mjwills